# Use big if clauses or stack them?

Tags: delphi, if-statement

what's a better way to do things?

```
if f1() and f2() then...
```

or

```
if f1() then
  if f2() then
```

or:

```
fBoolean1 := f1()
fBoolean2 := f2()

if fboolean1 and fboolean2 then...
```

In the first example  I'm not sure which of the two functions gets evaluated. In the second example f2 only gets evaluated if f1 evaluates true and in the third example both f1 and f2 get evaluated.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Third option has different behaviour if `f2()` has any side effects. As for your question, I use all three depending on the context. There's no place for dogma in programming.

Comment: The only factor I can see for picking one over the other is if any ONE of your if statements also has an else, then you would want to use your 2nd option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is smart. In your first sample, if `f1` returns `false`, then `f2` will not even be called (unless you change the default compiler settings by disabling *lazy evaluation* or *boolean short-circuit evaluation*). Hence, the first option is equivalent to the second one (again, unless you have changed the default settings).

Consequently, perfomance-wise, the two first options are better. Otherwise, it is a matter of taste. The second option will yield two blocks of code, with two levels of code indentation (if you follow the standard rules of indentation, as you seem to do). Perhaps you'd prefer the first option for this reason.

Of course, if you need to use the value returned by `f1` and `f2` later, perhaps several times, the third option is superior.

Comment: The thing I'm a bit worried about is that the compiler at some point might get smart and find out f2 is "lighter" and swap the evaluation order.

Comment: @Pieter B: No, that is impossible, because that would violate the [specification](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Boolean_Operators) of the language: **Short-circuit evaluation means strict left-to-right evaluation that stops as soon as the result of the entire expression is determined.** One often does things like `if (x = 0) or (5/x = 2) then` because one knows that lazy evaluation is enabled.